# Symfony 4 migration to Hostgator not logging in to the backend

Tags: php, authentication, symfony4

I'm trying to migrate my Symfony 4 project to HostGator. The issue is that I'm not able to login to the backend with no errors showing. The website is reading fine from the backend meaning there's no database issue. Locally, everything is working fine.

The only errors I'm getting in the var/log:

```
[2021-12-28T07:14:06.470829-06:00] request.INFO: Matched route "app_login". {"route":"app_login","route_parameters":{"_route":"app_login","_controller":"App\\Controller\\SecurityController::login"},"request_uri":"https://publiscreenmedia.com/new_website/admin/login","method":"POST"} []
[2021-12-28T07:14:06.509022-06:00] security.DEBUG: Checking for authenticator support. {"firewall_name":"main","authenticators":1} []
[2021-12-28T07:14:06.509143-06:00] security.DEBUG: Checking support on authenticator. {"firewall_name":"main","authenticator":"App\\Security\\LoginFormAuthenticator"} []
[2021-12-28T07:14:06.511112-06:00] security.DEBUG: Authenticator does not support the request. {"firewall_name":"main","authenticator":"App\\Security\\LoginFormAuthenticator"} []
```

Security.yaml:

```
security:
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/authenticator_manager.html
enable_authenticator_manager: true
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#c-hashing-passwords
password_hashers:
    Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface: 'auto'
    App\Entity\User:
        algorithm: auto

# https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
providers:
    # used to reload user from session & other features (e.g. switch_user)
    app_user_provider:
        entity:
            class: App\Entity\User
            property: email
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    main:
        lazy: true
        anonymous: false
        provider: app_user_provider
        custom_authenticator: App\Security\LoginFormAuthenticator
        logout:
            path: app_logout
            # where to redirect after logout
            # target: app_any_route

        # activate different ways to authenticate
        # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#firewalls-authentication

        # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/impersonating_user.html
        # switch_user: true

# Easy way to control access for large sections of your site
# Note: Only the *first* access control that matches will be used
access_control:
    # - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
    # - { path: ^/profile, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

SecurityController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationUtils;

class SecurityController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("admin/login", name="app_login")
     */
    public function login(AuthenticationUtils $authenticationUtils): Response
    {
        // if ($this->getUser()) {
        //     return $this->redirectToRoute('target_path');
        // }

        if($this->isGranted("IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY")) {
            return $this->redirectToRoute("admin_client_list");
        }
        

        // get the login error if there is one
        $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();
        // last username entered by the user
        $lastUsername = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();

        return $this->render('security/login.html.twig', ['last_username' => $lastUsername, 'error' => $error]);
    }

    /**
     * @Route("admin/logout", name="app_logout")
     */
    public function logout(): void
    {
        throw new \LogicException('This method can be blank - it will be intercepted by the logout key on your firewall.');
    }
}
```

LoginFormAuthenticator:

```
    <?php

namespace App\Security;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\AbstractLoginFormAuthenticator;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\Badge\CsrfTokenBadge;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\Badge\UserBadge;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\Credentials\PasswordCredentials;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\Passport;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\PassportInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Util\TargetPathTrait;

class LoginFormAuthenticator extends AbstractLoginFormAuthenticator
{
    use TargetPathTrait;

    public const LOGIN_ROUTE = 'app_login';

    private UrlGeneratorInterface $urlGenerator;

    public function __construct(UrlGeneratorInterface $urlGenerator)
    {
        $this->urlGenerator = $urlGenerator;
    }

    public function authenticate(Request $request): PassportInterface
    {
        $email = $request->request->get('email', '');

        $request->getSession()->set(Security::LAST_USERNAME, $email);

        return new Passport(
            new UserBadge($email),
            new PasswordCredentials($request->request->get('password', '')),
            [
                new CsrfTokenBadge('authenticate', $request->request->get('_csrf_token')),
            ]
        );
    }

    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, string $firewallName): ?Response
    {
        if ($targetPath = $this->getTargetPath($request->getSession(), $firewallName)) {
            return new RedirectResponse($targetPath);
        }

        // For example:
        return new RedirectResponse($this->urlGenerator->generate('main'));
        throw new \Exception('TODO: provide a valid redirect inside '.__FILE__);
    }

    protected function getLoginUrl(Request $request): string
    {
        return $this->urlGenerator->generate(self::LOGIN_ROUTE);
    }
}
```

Framework.yaml:

```
# see https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html
framework:
    secret: '%env(APP_SECRET)%'
    #csrf_protection: true
    http_method_override: true
    default_locale: en

    # Enables session support. Note that the session will ONLY be started if you read or write from it.
    # Remove or comment this section to explicitly disable session support.
    session:
        handler_id: session.handler.native_file
        # handler_id: null
        enabled: true
        cookie_secure: true
        cookie_samesite: lax
        storage_factory_id: session.storage.factory.native
        save_path: '%kernel.project_dir%/var/sessions/%kernel.environment%'

    #esi: true
    #fragments: true
    php_errors:
        log: true

when@test:
    framework:
        test: true
        session:
            storage_factory_id: session.storage.factory.mock_file
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just moved the website to the root and it worked!